# 型変換の警告が出る

Tags: c, x11

X window プログラミングで、

STRUCTURES
       The XTextProperty structure contains:

```
typedef struct {
        unsigned char *value;   /* property data */
        Atom encoding;  /* type of property */
        int format;     /* 8, 16, or 32 */
        unsigned long nitems;   /* number of items in value */
} XTextProperty;
```

を用いて

```
XTextProperty window_name;
```

と宣言し、

```
window_name.value = "hoge";
```

のように代入を行うと。

warning: assigning to 'unsigned char *' from 'char [2]'
      converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

ビルド時に上記のような警告が出力されます。

質問の内容としては

1. 警告が出ている原因が知りたい
2. 警告が出ないような記述の仕方が知りたい

です。

ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"hoge"`が`unsigned char`型のポインタではなく、暗黙的に型変換できないから警告されるのだと思います。
なので`window_name.value = (unsighed char*)"hoge";`としてあげれば良いように思います。